# I don't have the default apt (not apt-get) behavior after messing with packages. How do I get it back?

Tags: apt

I had to free some space on my disk so I've remove some packages. I wanted to delete boost related libs but I went a bit to fast and typed:

```
apt remove libboost*
```

After that I couldn't use apt:

```
$ apt
bash: /usr/local/bin/apt: No such file or directory
```

But I was still able to use 'apt-get'. I tried to reinstall some packages and after messing around I wasn't able to install packages with 'apt-get' anymore. I had to run it with "--fix-broken" which would uninstall the apt package. I did it and I've reinstalled it afterward but now when I use the 'apt' command I don't have access to all the features I had (like not having to type sudo in front of it as it would ask my password itself and saving it).

What should I do to have the "default" apt again ? Is it another package ? Is there some sort of config I've lost ?

I know it's a bit confused so I'm there if something is too fuzzy.

Edit: Here is the log of the apt call https://pastebin.com/uhXra2PD

Comment: Show us what you removed: /var/log/apt/history.log.

Comment: here you go https://pastebin.com/uhXra2PD